# friend function + operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

I am working on a project for class that is a sort of payroll. Part of the prompt says

"You may define a friend function that overloads << for displaying the Employee object information(i.e. the overloading << function will call the virtual print function.)"

I know what a friend function is, but I don't recall learning about the overloading << part. I tried searching for some easy copy paste implementation... but my compiler flares up no matter what I try.

How do I go about actually implementing this? Here's the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Base class
class Employee
{
public:
    Employee(string a, string b, string c, string d);
    ~Employee();
    int virtual earnings();
    void virtual print();
protected:
    string first, last, brithday, department;
};

Employee::Employee(string f, string l, string b, string d)
{
    first = f;
    last = l;
    brithday = b;
    department = d; //department code
    cout << "Employee created." << endl;
}

Employee::~Employee(void)
{
    cout << "Employee deleted." << endl;
}

int Employee::earnings()
{
    int earnings = 100; //To be added
    return earnings;
}

void Employee::print()
{
    //IDK 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't let the `<<` operator confuse you. Overloaded operators are, at the end of the day, just **another way to name functions**.

If you have this piece of code:

```
int i = 1;
std::string s = "x";
double d = 0.5;
std::cout << s << i << d;
```

Then this is just another way of saying:

```
int i = 1;
std::string s = "x";
double d = 0.5;
std::operator<<(std::cout, s).operator<<(i).operator<<(d);
```

Which, by the way, makes it more obvious that the chaining calls work because `operator<<` returns a reference to the stream itself. Note that there are two different kinds of `operator<<` involved here: the one for `std::string` is a [free-standing function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) taking a `std::ostream` reference argument, the ones for `int` and `double` are `std::ostream` [member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).

Equipped with this knowledge, it's easy to imagine, for a moment, that we would just be dealing with normally named functions, e.g. "print":

```
int i = 1;
std::string s = "x";
double d = 0.5;
print(std::cout, s).print(i).print(d);
```

In fact, you can imagine that there is no *overloading* but all of them have different names. This makes the whole thing even easier to understand:

```
int i = 1;
std::string s = "x";
double d = 0.5;
printStringOnStream(std::cout, s).printInt(i).printDouble(d);
```

If you want to provide `std::ostream` printing for your own class, all you have to do is do it like `std::string`: provide a free-standing `operator<<` which takes a `std::ostream` reference and a (const) reference to your object, and which returns a reference to the stream:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, Employee const &employee)
{
    // ...
    return stream;

}
```

Now the `// ...` part is where the friend thing comes into play. In order to properly print an `Employee`, you'll need access to all its private members. The easiest way to provide this access without exposing it to the whole public is to declare your `operator<<` a friend of `Employee`:

```
class Employee
{
    // ...
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, Employee const &employee);
}; 

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, Employee const &employee)
{
    stream << employee.earnings; // and so on
    return stream;
}
```

There you go, perfect printing for your Employee:

```
std::cout << "xyz" << my_employee << "abc" << 0.5 << 1;
```